# Are these types of proofs always valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Task: prove that if **c|ab** and **gcd(c,a)=d**, then **c|db**.

Is this proof correct?

> If **c|db** then **ck=db** for some integer **k**.
>
> We know that because **c|ab**, **ch=ab**, for some integer **h**,
>
> and that because **(c,a)=d**, we know that **cx+ay=d**, for some integers **x** and **y**.
>
> We just need to get to **ck=db** from **ch=ab** and **cx+ay=d**.
>
> $$
> cx+ay=d → a={d-cx\over y}
> $$
>   Now substitute this **a** to the equation **ch=ab**:
>   $$
> ch={d-cx\over y}b → ch={db-cxb\over y} → chy=db-cxb → chy+cxb=db 
> → c(hy+xb)=db
> $$
>   and now just let **(hy+xb)=k**, and we have **ck=db**.

Is this kind of proof a proper, rigorous proof? I know that it's not the most elegant one, I just want to know if it works. I'm new to these "algebra trickery" types of proofs, and I'd like to know, is something like this, i.e. working your way from some equations to other ones, always a proper proof (assuming there aren't any mistakes in the algebra)?

Comment: Yeah these things look quite dull to work with but they are used ONLY when there is no way out.....However your question has better solutions.

Comment: Looks ok, maybe a little overly complicated.  as $cx+ay=d$ we deduce $cbx+aby=db$ but $c$ divides both terms on the left, hence it divides the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but not optimal.

**Just a suggestion**

$$cx+ay=d\implies bcx+\underbrace{ba}_{=ch}y=db\implies c(bx+hy)=bd$$
what prove the claim.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

$$gcd(c,a)=d \Rightarrow a=md, c=nd $$ where $gcd(m,n)=1$
$$c\big|ab \Rightarrow nd\big|mdb \Rightarrow n\big|mb \Rightarrow n\big|b \Rightarrow b=nk$$
$$db=dnk=ck \Rightarrow c\big|db$$